# Why is it considered a good practice to make session scoped objects Serializable?

Tags: java, session, web-applications, servlets, session-state

I often hear people saying that **session scoped** objects should implement `Serializable` ? Why it is so ? What will be the result if one doesn't do this ? Why not make this a part of the servlet specification then ? I know Tomcat doesn't complain if we do not do this . What about other app servers like JBoss, WebSphere or Weblogic ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This allows the servlet container to either store the contents of a
>   session on disk, or to transfer session contents over the network to
>   another server.

Why does the container need to store session on the disk (passivation)? Perhaps when the memory is full. When the session is needed again, it retrieves it from the disk back into memory (activation).

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=110

Comment: Why is not a part of servlet spec then ? Because if we do not follow this rule stringently , how would the fail over work in case of load balancers ?

Comment: No the servlet spec wouldn't mandate it. There are sensitive information that you will not wish to have them serialized. Such like bank account number, secrets etc. For the purpose of the later, fields may be marked transient.

Comment: `NotSerializableException` would occur when your container tries to Serialize the object that does not implement Serializable.

Comment: It's not part of the servlet spec, because passivation and replication are not part of the servlet spec.  Those are container specific features.

Comment: Also to support session failover and shared session.

Answer (score 2):

It allows container to move the session objects over the network or store them on a disk. It will helpful when you cluster your application with different nodes of server running in different physical boxes.