# values not binding to String array from h:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am trying to add do a simple selectManycheckbox example but the values are not getting binded to the bean. I am getting

```
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=form1:subscriptions[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Conversion Error setting value 'asis base appl' for '#{HomePage.outputType}'.), detail=(Conversion Error setting value 'asis base appl' for '#{HomePage.outputType}'.)]
```

This is my jsf page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>

    <h:form id="form1">

        <h:panelGrid border="1" columns="2"
            style='color: black; font-size: 16px; font-family: "Times New Roman", Serif; font-weight: bold'>
            <h:outputLabel value="Select values"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:selectManyCheckbox id="subscriptions" value="#{HomePage.outputType}" layout="pageDirection">
                <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="ASIS" itemValue="asis"/>
                <f:selectItem id="item3" itemLabel="BASE" itemValue="base"/>
                <f:selectItem id="item7" itemLabel="APPLIED" itemValue="appl"/>
            </h:selectManyCheckbox>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton type="submit" action="#{HomePage.genOutput}" value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my bean class HomePage.java:

```
package com.MH;
import com.MH.WebPageSaver;
public class HomePage{
    private String[] outputType;

    /*various getter setters*/


    public String genOutput() throws Exception{
     if (outputType != null)
      {
        System.out.println("if");
            WebPageSaver w = new WebPageSaver();
            try{
                System.out.println("inside try");
                            /*independent function below works fine*/
                String msg = w.generateOutput(outputType);
                return msg;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                return "error";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(outputType);
            System.out.println("else");
            return "error";
        }
    }


}
```

The nav rule is to the same page irrespective of the msg.

```
    <faces-config  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>HomePage</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.MH.HomePage</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/HomePage.jsp</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/HomePage.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/HomePage.jsp</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/HomePage.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Kindly let me know what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, I'm not getting your conversion error with my code. The only thing I can think of is that you probably defined your `setOutputType`method wrong. It should be

```
public void setOutputType(String[] outputType) {
        this.outputType = outputType;
}
```

since `h:selectManyCheckBox` need to set an array of `String` in your case when the form is submitted.

I'm trying to be thorough here so here is my `HomePage.java`

```
package com.MH;
public class HomePage implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String[] outputType;

    /*various getter setters*/
    public String[] getOutputType() {
        return outputType;
    }

    public void setOutputType(String[] outputType) {
        this.outputType = outputType;
    }

    public String genOutput() throws Exception{
     if (outputType != null)
      {
        System.out.println("if");
            WebPageSaver w = new WebPageSaver();
            try{
                System.out.println("inside try");
                            /*independent function below works fine*/
                String msg = w.generateOutput(outputType);
                return msg;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                return "error";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(outputType);
            System.out.println("else");
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Not much different from yours. The `generateOutput(String[])` from `WebPageSaver` on my end is simply returning the `String` success. I even made a simple test.jsp to see if values were being set and they are. (Caution: it's sloppy)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:outputText value="#{HomePage.outputType[0]}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{HomePage.outputType[1]}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{HomePage.outputType[2]}"/>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

and I edited one of your navigation cases

```
<from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/test.jsp</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

**COMMENTS**

Not sure why you have `throws Exception` in your `genOuput` since you are already catching it within the mehod. It is not needed (unless your constructor for `WebPageSaver` throws something)

Also, session scoped should implement `java.io.Serializable`. Not required but a good practice

[Why is it considered a good practice to make session scoped objects Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262759/why-is-it-considered-a-good-practice-to-make-session-scoped-objects-serializable)

Comment: OP is using JSF 1.2. Your answer assumes JSF 2.0. Retry on JSF 1.2 and discover the hell.

Comment: ok Andy, Lets assume the code works and i am trying to display what ever checkboxes am ticking in the jsp page. What Lester has said is correct. but omnifaces is not in jsf1.2. What else could be the solution? I hope am not confusing you.

Comment: @Andy Well i think your code and mine is virtually the same. But when i run i still get the conversion error. I tried selectmanyListbox and even that threw the same error. I used a different IDE and even then i get the error. What more could be the problem ?

Comment: @satsamsk I'm really not sure :(  I'm not getting any errors on my end. Can you post HomPage.java entirely ?

Comment: @Andy I dont want to say this, I of course used a String [] to bind selectManyCheckbox values. It was not working even then. On a friend's advice I replaced all my jar files and it worked fine. I wasted 2 days in this. Thanks for all your patient explanantions. Appreciate it!!